# No NotRegistered message for an uninstalled registration_id

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I got a registration Id using:

```
String regid = (GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this)).register("My_Sender_ID");
```

and stored it in a database on my server. Later when then Application is uninstalled and I try to send a message I expected a **NotRegistered** error message, looking at which I would delete the corresponding Id from the database.

But the problem is it still returns me a **message_id** just like any other success case. I wanted to test for some more time and waited for an hour and now I get the proper message.

```
[error] => NotRegistered
```

So, is this delay expected?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this delay is expected.

On the first attempt to send the message after un-installing your app, the GCM server attempted to send it to the device and found out that your app was not registered for GCM on that device anymore.

On the second attempt to send the message after the un-installation you got the `NotRegistered` error, because this time the GCM server knew that this registration ID was no longer registered.

You didn't have to wait an hour to try sending again.

> Note: When users uninstall an application, it is not automatically
>   unregistered on GCM. It is only unregistered when the GCM server tries
>   to send a message to the device and the device answers that the
>   application is uninstalled or it does not have a broadcast receiver
>   configured to receive com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE intents.
>   At that point, your server should mark the device as unregistered (the
>   server will receive a NotRegistered error).

(quote from [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html))

Comment: `On the second attempt to send the message after the un-installation you got the NotRegistered error`. I actually tried 10+ times. Finally tried waiting for some time.

Comment: @user1537779 That's interesting. Google don't specify how long it takes the GCM server to detect that the registration ID is no longer registered, but when I tried it, I got the `NotRegistered` error immediately on my second attempt to send the message.

Comment: Fine. Just wanted to confirm. Will try again. Thank you.

Comment: Two days back while trying it out the NotRegistered message was sent in the second attempt. But today, that's not happening despite waiting for hours :(

Comment: This seems to be happening for a lot of people. Might very well be a bug on their end. @MichaelMassey

Answer (score 0):

To add additional detail to this, Eran's answer is correct, but I found that after making multitudinous attempts at generating a NotRegistered response I would get back a messageId as if the app was still installed on the device.  I found [this message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-gcm/gScadiCjK-g/ijgbnPETrekJ) on the google group which explains that the time_to_live field is a part of the problem.  Apparently the default time_to_live value is 4 weeks, so you could be waiting quite a while for a NotRegistered response.  I set the time_to_live to 90 seconds and received a NotRegistered response on the second attempt.  Hopefully this will help someone out there as this caused me quite a headache when I was trying to figure this out.

See [the google GCM documentation site](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#request) for a further explanation of the GCM message format that details how time_to_live should be added to the message.